# A real number can have a complex nth root. Can a nonreal complex number have a real nth root?

Tags: complex-numbers

A real number may have a complex $n^{\text{th}}$ root. Can a non-real complex number have a real $n^{\text{th}}$ root?

Comment: By 'non real complex number' do you mean an imaginary number? Also, whilst I think I understand what you're trying to say, the question as you've presented it makes no sense

Comment: @mrnovice how does the question make *no sense* if you think you've understood what they're trying to say?

Comment: That's a fair point

Answer (score 5):

> Can a nonreal complex number have a real nth root?

Hint:  can a real number raised to the $n^{th}$ power be a non-real complex number?